# Would rotation of extracted components/factors after PCA/EFA affect results of a subsequent regression analysis?

Tags: r, pca, factor-analysis

To use the scores of the extracted components/factors in a further regression analysis, like mixed effects model regression as predictors to an outcome variable or DV. Would be there any discrepancies in the results coming out of the regression analysis when using scores of the following scenarios (`psych` package in R):
- `none` non-rotated principal components
- `varimax` orthogonally rotated principal components
- `promax` obliquely rotated principal components
- `promax` obliquely rotated factors using `ml` (maximum likelihood) extraction
- `promax` obliquely rotated factors using `pa` (principal axes) extraction?

Would it be invalid to use any of the above scores in a further regression analysis? any known issues in this field? or previous similar experiences?

Comment: The report about your analyses was needless, really. The title and "Question" would suffice. `Limitation`? No limitation: you may do whatever you want. `Consequences/differences`? There will be, some. What kind of? Please try it, to see! If you come across differences which you cannot explain yourself - then ask about these here.

Comment: @ttnphns, question was edited as suggested.